# how to style drop down button in ASPxComboBox devexpress

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, devexpress

[image]

the first combobox is a dx:ASPxComboBox using from devexpress I want it to look like the second one in picture drop down list from asp.net

How can I style a Combobox to look like  the second drop down list from asp.net in picture
I tried this solution 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q513816 
but still not look the same drop down list 
 The HTML Code for the  :

```
      <td style="text-align: right">
       <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server"   
        DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
          EnableIncrementalFiltering="True" 
           IncrementalFilteringMode="StartsWith" 
          ValueType="System.String" Width="205px">
          <ButtonStyle Paddings-Padding="0px">
          </ButtonStyle>
          <Border BorderStyle="None" />
          <DropDownButton>
              <Image Height="25px" Url="images/button.png" Width="15px">
              </Image>
          </DropDownButton>
          </dx:ASPxComboBox>
        </td>
```

drop down list HTML code :

```
    <td style="text-align: right">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLBranchName" runat="server" Width="205px" 
                    Font-Size="Large">
      </asp:DropDownList>
     </td>
```

my CSS :

```
.cont .tableSection
          {
           float:right;
            border:2px solid black;
           width:100%;
          direction:rtl;
         border-radius:10px;
          margin:5px auto;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS you've tried so far and point out what, exactly, you're having problems with?

Comment: @Shaggy I updated the question I want DropDownButton in dx:ASPxComboBox to look like DropDownButton in drop down list